# Dynamically Adding a Border Based on Rows Left in Each Section (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, dynamically-generated

I created a macro that is pulling in data from another sheet and pastes it into a new spreadsheet. It pulls in 3 main sections of data. It pastes it all, does a VLOOKUP on the corresponding columns it needs information based on what it pulled in. After it's done that, I have a "Remove" macro that removes the empty rows so they spacing is cropped down. I need to now add a border around those three different sections. The issue is, I have no experience with macros/VBA so I am trying my best to get this together but if I create a macro to put a border around what's left after it's removed empty spaces, it is not dynamic. So thus, if I did it for another spreadsheet that had more rows in each section, it wouldn't put the border around the right areas. I will need it to dynamically look through each of my three sections and see where the last row with information is and then put a border around that.

So here is a quick example: Say I have three empty sections currently before I've pulled in my data. Section one ranges from cells B1:K50. Section two ranges from B52:K100. Section three ranges from B105:K150. Once I hit my "pull in data" macro, it will auto populate those cells but lets say all those extra rows I have for each section wasn't used, I will have my "Remove" macro remove those extra. So lets say after it's removed those extra rows, it'll shift up where my sections 2 and sections 3 were. Then the final step will be to have it search to see where the sections begin and end and add a border around each of those sections. I can paste my code and we can go from there since I figured that'd be the best since I don't actually fully understand the syntax.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Better to add your code

Comment: [Add Cell Borders](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Adding Cell Borders)

Comment: [Add Cell Borders](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Adding%20Cell%20Borders)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Sub borders()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startOfNextSection As Range

'Section 1

'Check if there is only 1 row of data in Section 1
If IsEmpty(Range("b2")) Then
    lastRow = 1
Else
    lastRow = Range("b1").End(xlDown).Row
End If

With Range("B1", Cells(lastRow, 11))
    .borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With

'Section 2

Set startOfNextSection = Cells(lastRow, 2).End(xlDown)

'Check if there is only 1 row of data in Section 2
If IsEmpty(startOfNextSection.Offset(1, 0)) Then
    lastRow = startOfNextSection.Row
Else
    lastRow = startOfNextSection.End(xlDown).Row
End If

With Range(startOfNextSection, Cells(lastRow, 11))
    .borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With

'Section 3

Set startOfNextSection = Cells(lastRow, 2).End(xlDown)

'Check if there is only 1 row of data in Section 3
If IsEmpty(startOfNextSection.Offset(1, 0)) Then
    lastRow = startOfNextSection.Row
Else
    lastRow = startOfNextSection.End(xlDown).Row
End If

With Range(startOfNextSection, Cells(lastRow, 11))
    .borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Here are just examples of what I mean for clarification:
1) after data pulls in: http://postimg.org/image/gxyl8o7mv/
2) after removal of extra rows: http://postimg.org/image/c0fnbjvuf/
3) goal of what I want it to look like: http://postimg.org/image/islexxtw3/

Will the code you wrote above work?
"Remove code": http://postimg.org/image/sgo3va513/

I tried your code above but nothing happened